# There isn't the classes.jar under ../release/ in Android Studio Release mode

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm new to Android Studio 1.1.0. I want to build a android library project and output the JAR file. I have chosen the Build Variants as the Release mode.

However, after building the project, there isn't the classes.jar file under the *build/intermediates/bundles/release/* path.

There are the files/directory as followings:

AndroidManifest.xml
R.txt
aapt/
aidl/
assets/

But when I set the Build Variants as the Debug mode.

There are the output file/dir list under *build/intermediates/bundles/debug* path:

AndroidManifest.xml 
R.txt
aapt
aidl
assets
**classes.jar**
res

What's the problem ? How to solve it ?

**UPDATE**:
post the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}

task releaseJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('../releases')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'test.jar')
}
```

Comment: How are you building your library? Just by running the Gradle sync in Android Studio? Are you building it from the command line?

Comment: @ Daniel A. González I just run in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @ Daniel A. González's tip, I use the command

```
./gradlew releaseJar
```

the releaseJar task is defined as following:

```
task releaseJar(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'build') {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('../releases')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'testjar.jar')
}
```

Thank @Daniel A. González for your comment.

Comment: "gradlew releaseJar" worked for me.
It didnt work with the initial period and forward slash "./gradlew releaseJar"
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what you put, you can put a line after you define releaseJar like this:

```
assemble.finalizedBy releaseJar
```

And the task will run every time it is assembled.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work. Maybe I have missed something.

Comment: Could you update your question with your latest build.gradle with these changes? Maybe there is an error somewhere.

Comment: Actually I told you the wrong thing, edited the answer. Basically, use finalizedBy instead of dependsOn; that way the task runs after and not before.